# Как прочитать из properties файла в html?

Tags: property, html, java

- Есть файл links.properties.
- Есть html страница, в которой нужно сослаться на урл, которая в свою очередь присвоена свойству link в этом property файле.

Как прочитать из properties файла в html?

Comment: Не считайте за спам //blog.dimka3210.ru/2013/03/javautilproperties.html
Сам воевал)

Comment: Как вытащить в java я знаю. Как потом записать в html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы пытаетесь реализовать (подменить в исходном текстовом файле некоторые поля на конкретные значения), называется "шаблонизация". И на текущий момент существует довольно широкий выбор готовых решений, выбирайте на свой вкус, в зависимости от исходной задачи:

- [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)
- [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/)
- [Mixer2](http://mixer2.org/site/)
- [Rythm](http://rythmengine.org/)
- [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/)
- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- JSP
- XSLT
- Многочисленные варианты шаблонизации на клиентской стороне в JavaScript (handlebars, mustache, jade, underscore).

Comment: Thymeleaf помог, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно так попробовать:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("\path\to\links.properties");
    prop.load(input);
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("url1"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("url2"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("url3"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```